# May i use jsonStringify() method on List<String>?

Tags: kotlin, gatling

I'm trying to make custom body with the result of previous response as a list of strings.
So it is a List which is stored as session variable.
May i use jsonStringify() method on this session variable?
When i use it as is, i've got that JSON is not valid because it pastes list without brackets.

Example:

```kotlin
.body(StringBody(
                """
                {
                    "id": "$id",
                    "items": $items
                }
            """.trimIndent()
```

It sends `[item1, item2]` instead of `["item1", "item2"]`

I've done this by lambda but i think that was not really good.

```kotlin
.body(StringBody{
                session ->
                val items = session.get<List<String>>("items")?.map { "\"$it\"" }
                val id = session.getString("id")?: "unknown"
                """
                {
                    "id": "$id",
                    "items": $items
                }
            """.trimIndent()
```

Comment: "May I" based on what? If you just want to know if it works, why not just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Proof: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core/src/test/scala/io/gatling/core/json/JsonSpec.scala#L73-L76

(some blah blah to meet SoF's 30 chars requirement)

Comment: Thank you, i've got expected result now.